# how to use load/next/error when there may be embedded blocks?

Tags: rebol, rebol3

transcode/next/error returns the first loaded value, and the position after the value, so you can then go to load the next value:

```
>> transcode/next/error to binary! " a b c "
== [a #{2062206320}]
```

Or you get an error, and the position after the error value:

```
>> transcode/next/error to binary! " 1a b c " 
== [make error! [                             
    code: 200                             
    type: 'Syntax                         
    id: 'invalid                          
    arg1: "integer"                       
    arg2: "1a"                            
    arg3: none                            
    near: "(line 1) 1a b c "              
    where: [transcode]                    
] #{2062206320}]
```

But if the value to load is a block, and there's an error inside the block, then

- you get an error!
- the position after the error value, and
- the good values inside the block are discarded:

like here

```
>> transcode/next/error to binary! "[ a b 1c ]"
== [make error! [
    code: 200
    type: 'Syntax
    id: 'invalid
    arg1: "integer"
    arg2: "1c"
    arg3: none
    near: "(line 1) [ a b 1c ]"
    where: [transcode]
] #{205D}]
```

My current[*] solution is, to correct the input string, and restart from the last position. This way I am reloading the whole block, to get it in one go.

Is there any better way to handle this?

[*] see here https://github.com/IngoHohmann/rebol3-tools/blob/master/load-all.r3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a loop that invokes each instance of `'transcode`, you could precede transcode with your own mechanism to process block characters `[]()`. You then become responsible for arbitrating valid blocks, but since your goal is to load *any* data, you will likely need to handle block delimiters that aren't balanced anyhow.

All that you'd need is a mechanism that worked like transcode, but for block delimiters:

```
block-transcode: func [source [binary!] /local symbol][
    if parse source [
        any space  ; space should be defined
        copy symbol [#"[" | #"]" | #"(" | #")"]
        source: to end
    ][
        reduce [symbol source]
    ]
]
```

Of course, this wouldn't check for blocks within parens within paths, but it's a start...